# set item states programmatically

Tags: android

my App has a quickaction class that creates a popup with button when a certain button in my adapter is pressed... works, everything fine. But now i want to keep my ListItems background set android:state_focused="true" and android:state_pressed="true" while my quickactionpopup is still up. Just would look alot better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting background color in onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) of OnItemSelectedListener.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html